# Saas Architecture and design suggestion.. Any existing products that simplifies the design

Tags: multithreading, wcf, multi-tenant, saas

I have the following setup

1. Customer access -> Web application -> Database
2. A Server application (console based) for each customer running in the Server continuously that downloads data from various locations and update database

So if i am having 100 customers, i will need to run 100 console applications in the server.

If there is any problem/crash with one server application(because of specific kind of data i am downloading), i will be able to fix it by restarting or patching.

I took this approach as i initially thought it is easy to maintain. But feeling not anymore. I am sure there are better tools available outside to manage this kind of scenarios. If you know any please let me know. I should be able start/restart/patch/monitor server usage/check for crash on the server application through some nice GUI.
Or may be there is a way to write one multi-threaded application to serve all customers instead of one for each. And there may be a way to shutdown/restart the any customer's thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to use a threaded application that can set your tenant context for the process that needs to be done for that thread.

This way, we have 1 app for all customers and van make use of application events and mailers to notify on case of any error.

An audit table with track of the various data processing status can help in a GUI to be built for tracking the progress on a tenant basis.

HTH